# add and save a circle mask box image

Tags: image, node.js, canvas

I would like to apply a transparent circle mask to png pictures send to my node.js server; so that I can display circle shaped picture in older browser and email clients.

I am already using node-canvas to resize and crop my pictures, so I was wondering if this kind of picture manipulation could be done through the canvas api.

Comment: can you describe the operation in more detail?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to write the code for what I wanted here it is

{Image} = Canvas = require 'canvas'
fs = require 'fs'

img = new Image
  img.onload = ->

```
canvas = new Canvas 200, 200
cxt = canvas.getContext '2d'
cxt.drawImage img, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh
cxt.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-atop"

cxt.beginPath()
cxt.arc 100, 100, 50, 0, Math.PI*2, true
cxt.fill()
cxt.closePath()

canvas.toBuffer (err, buf) ->
  return cb(err) if err
  fs.writeFile  "/tmp/dest.jpeg", buf, -> console.log 'test done !'

img.src = '/tmp/src.jpeg'
```